# Does Entity Framework 4 support multi-databases?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With entity framework, could I, say at fairly high up in the stack set which database I want to connect to, and then have EF use that for all queries?

This is not a scenario where you have a different db per model, but rather have all models connect to the same database, but this database could be different depending on some criteria (like say the URL or a sub-domain).

If yes, what implications would this have with db pooling etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your ObjectContext, a parameter for the constructor is the connection string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx

There should be no implications on pooling.

Comment: is the objectcontext something that is set globally before an action fires, and then closed?  i.e. can I do this once per request?

Comment: Well, object contexts should not be shared across threads and should generally have a short lifespan (per unit of work)...then it is disposed. So, yes, it's (the connection string) something you could change for each creation of an ObjectContext.

Comment: so creating it and destroying it and the begining/end of the page request is safe then right? best-practice? (like in MVC before/after executing an action)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. It's simply a matter of using the proper connection string when creating your ObjectContext, that connects you to the database you want to use. We do this frequently.

Comment: But I assume exact same database(-schema), not a switch from MS-SQL to oracle?

Comment: Correct. The provider is specified in the SSDL which is compiled into the assembly. If you wanted to do this switch, you could change the edmx compile action to copy to output folder and manually switch the ssdl to use a different provider at runtime. More here http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Multiple-database-support-with-Entity-Framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you use your `DbContext` you can simply change the connectionString before you do any queries.

For Example, you can simply change the Initial Catalog name:

```
    YourDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "data source=LAPKEVIN\\SQLKEVIN;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase";
```